# Как в Sping задать выполнение двухфазной транзакции?

Tags: база-данных, spring

Есть четыре источника:две базы данных oracle, один mssql и плоский файл. В обычной практике я  использую XADataSource. В spring я не нашел способа работать в одной транзакции с несколькими разнородными источниками. Где можно найти описание двухфазной транзакции в springe(работающие примеры)?

Comment: Спринг поддерживает XA https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.jta, можно менеджер транзакций из [Java EE сервера приложений](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.jta.javaee), а можно встроенный.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, спасибо за "наводку", но информации в разделе 7.9.14 чрезвычайно мало. А сервер приложений  так это да,  на то они  сервер приложений чтобы  предоставлять  такую  возможность.